# What triggers Jobs in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm learning how Spark works inside Databricks. I understand how shuffling causes stages within jobs, but I don't understand what causes jobs. I thought the relationship was one job per action, but sometimes many jobs happen per action.

E.g.

```
val initialDF = spark                                                       
  .read                                                                     
  .parquet("/mnt/training/wikipedia/pagecounts/staging_parquet_en_only_clean/")   

val someDF = initialDF
   .orderBy($"project")

someDF.show
```

triggers two jobs, one to peek at the schema and one to do the `.show`.

And the same code with `.groupBy` instead

```
val initialDF = spark                                                       
  .read                                                                     
  .parquet("/mnt/training/wikipedia/pagecounts/staging_parquet_en_only_clean/")   

val someDF = initialDF
  .groupBy($"project").sum()

someDF.show
```

...triggers nine jobs.

Replacing `.show` with `.count`,  the `.groupBy` version triggers two jobs, and the `.orderBy` version triggers three.

Sorry I can't share the data to make this reproducible, but was hoping to understand the rules of when jobs are created in abstract. Happy to share the results of `.explain` if that's helpful.

Comment: What is the easiest way to download files such as "/mnt/training/wikipedia/pagecounts/staging_parquet_en_only_clean/" localy? Mounting script from "Microsoft Azure Databricks for Data Engineering" course does not work in my Databricks env.

Answer (score 2):

Normally it is 1:1 as you state. That is to say, **1 Action** results in **1 Job** with 1..N Stages with M Tasks per Stage, and Stages which may be skipped.

However, some Actions trigger extra Jobs 'under water'. E.g. **pivot**: if you pass only the columns as parameter and not the values for the pivot, then Spark has to fetch all the distinct values first so as to generate columns, performing a collect, i.e. an **extra Job**.

show is also a special case of extra Job(s) being generated.

Answer (score 1):

`show` without an argument shows the first 20 rows as a result.
When `show` is triggered on dataset, it gets converted to `head(20)` action which in turn get converted to `limit(20)` action .
`show` -> `head` -> `limit`

***About `limit`***
Spark executes `limit` in an incremental fashion until the limit query is satisfied.
In its first attempt, it tries to retrieve the required number of rows from one partition.
If the limit requirement was not satisfied, in the second attempt, it tries to retrieve the required number of rows from 4 partitions (determined by `spark.sql.limit.scaleUpFactor`, default 4).  and after which 16 partitions are processed and so on until either the limit is satisfied or data is exhausted.

In each of the attempts, a separate job is spawned.

code reference: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkPlan.scala#L365

Comment: That's @DaRkMaN, could you comment on `.groupBy` with `.count` (instead of `.show` as mentioned above as well?

Comment: Can we check if the job is spawned for listing of files(I believe a job is spawned for this operation to parallelize listing of cloud storage), schema inference(set spark.sql.hive.caseSensitiveInferenceMode=NEVER_INFER and check if a job reduces)?

Comment: I guess the larger lesson here is that many actions have other actions wrapped inside them....so it's still one job per action, but not always one action per action.

Comment: There is no one to one mapping b/w jobs and actions.

Comment: re-reading what I wrote before, yeah that was a confusing way of saying, there's no 1-1 mapping.